# Unable to connect debian prod while building the image from a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, debian

I was trying replicate this project https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula.git and there is dockerfile in this project . I tried to build image out of dockerfile but while building image there is an error saying " Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http:"

I tried to search related issues in stackoverflow but didn't got any clear idea how to solve the issue .

```
FROM jruby:9.1-jdk

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN echo 'gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri' >> /.gemrc

ENV GEM_HOME /usr/local/bundle
ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
RUN gem install bundler -v '< 2' \
  && bundle config --global path "$GEM_HOME" \
  && bundle config --global bin "$GEM_HOME/bin"
```

This is the error which i got while building the image :

```
Step 1/17 : FROM jruby:9.1-jdk
 ---> 0de61e330d81
Step 2/17 : RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && apt-get install -y build-essential
 ---> Running in 5819127c82e0
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Could not connect to prod.debian.map.fastly.net:80 (151.101.200.204). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (130.89.148.77). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 130.89.148.77 80]
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 130.89.148.77 80]
Err:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
  Could not connect to prod.debian.map.fastly.net:80 (151.101.200.204). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (128.31.0.63). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 128.31.0.63 80]
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not connect to prod.debian.map.fastly.net:80 (151.101.200.204). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to deb.debian.org:80 (130.89.148.77). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 130.89.148.77 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Could not connect to prod.debian.map.fastly.net:80 (151.101.200.204). - connect (111: Connection refused) Could not connect to security.debian.org:80 (128.31.0.63). - connect (111: Connection refused) [IP: 128.31.0.63 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to deb.debian.org:http: [IP: 130.89.148.77 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package apt-transport-https
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update  && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && apt-get install -y build-essential' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: This is always an issue with your local networking setup; it’s not the type of programming question SO can help with.

Comment: Is there any way i can solve this @DavidMaze

Answer (score 1):

You have to include proxy parameters into the Dockerfile :

ENV http_proxy http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX

ENV https_proxy https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX

Answer (score -3):

If you are working through a VPN, try to disconnect it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33432587)